# grep output of expect script

Tags: bash, scripting, expect

I'm trying to run some expect language, and grep/parse the output all in one script. I want to grep the output of and look for "error" (I should note that standard linux commands like awk, sed, grep, etc are not available on the remote VPlexcli machine)

```
#!/bin/bash

expect - << EOF
# connect to vplexcli
spawn vplexcli
# Look for login prompt
expect -re "Name:"
# Send login
send "service\r"
# Look for password prompt
expect -re "Password:"
# Send password
send "letmein123\r"
expect -re "VPlexcli:/> "
send "ll /clusters/cluster-1/storage-elements/\r"
expect -re "VPlexcli:/> "
send "exit\r"
EOF
```

Output looks like this:

```
VPD83T3:6006016036c02c00e217465c0516e211  ok            APM00121002844.SPA  APM00121002844.SPB  both        0x002e000000000000  implicit-explicit
VPD83T3:6006016036c02c00e4dc0671f907e211  ok            APM00121002844.SPA  APM00121002844.SPB  both        0x0010000000000000  implicit-explicit
VPD83T3:6006016036c02c00ec79619bdd08e211  error         APM00121002844.SPA  APM00121002844.SPB  none                            implicit-explicit
VPD83T3:6006016036c02c00f0bfd3dedd08e211  error         APM00121002844.SPA  APM00121002844.SPB  none                            implicit-explicit
```

Comment: Please show some typical output from the expect program

Comment: grep "error"... and then what? Note that you can `expect` the string "error" in your expect script, and `exit` with an error code if matched.

Comment: I just want a list returned to me with items on the "error" lines.

    VPD83T3:6006016036c02c00f0bfd3dedd08e211

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the output and parse it within expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect to vplexcli
spawn vplexcli
# Look for login prompt
expect -re "Name:"
# Send login
send "service\r"
# Look for password prompt
expect -re "Password:"
# Send password
send "letmein123\r"
expect -re "VPlexcli:/> "
send "ll /clusters/cluster-1/storage-elements/\r"
expect -re "(.*)VPlexcli:/> "

foreach line [split $expect_out(1,string) \n] {
    if {[string match *error* $line]} {
        puts $line
    }
}

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#!/bin/bash

(expect - << EOF

...

EOF
) | while read line; do if [[ "$line" =~ "error" ]]; then  echo $line; fi; done
```

Surprised you don't have grep.